# In Ansible, how can I iterate over stdout with an array?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.6.3

I have the simple task, which gets the AWS ARNs in my jenkins ECS cluster

```
  tasks:
  - command: aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster jenkins
    register: jenkins_ecs_containers

  - debug: var=jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout
```

and has the following output

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout": {
        "containerInstanceArns": [
           "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0", 
           "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn1"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I iterate over the ARNs? I tried

```
- debug: var=item
  with_items: jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns
```

gives

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns) => {
    "item": "jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns"
}
```

or

```
- debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{ jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns }}"
```

gives

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'containerInstanceArns'"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/cfouts/git-repos/ansible/playbooks/loop.retry
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file with your output.  So I used `set_fact`.  Otherwise, it's just a string, not a JSON object:

```
  tasks:

  - command: cat files/stdout.txt
    register: result

  - debug: var=result.stdout

  - set_fact:
      jenkins_ecs_containers: "{{ result.stdout }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ jenkins_ecs_containers.containerInstanceArns }}"
```

This gave me the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": {
        "containerInstanceArns": [
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0", 
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn1"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack, that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item[1] }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ jenkins_ecs_containers }}"
    - containerInstanceArns
```

Go through this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop), it will make it clearer.

Comment: That would fail, first, because `jenkins_ecs_containers` does not contain `containerInstanceArns`.  Replace that with `jenkins_ecs_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns`, and you get the same error as the O.P. did.

Comment: Check this out now

Comment: That doesn't work either: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got '[]'"}`